# Extract substring from rows with regex and remove rows with duplicate substring

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a text file with some rows in the following form

```
*,[anything, even blanks],[dog|log|frog],[dog|log|frog],[0|1],[0|1],[0|1]
```

I would like to remove duplicate rows that have the same value for `*` (**case insensitive**), ie anything left of `,[anything, even blanks],[dog|log|frog],[dog|log|frog],[0|1],[0|1],[0|1]`

For example here's a sample text file

```
test,bar,log,dog,0,0,0
one
foo,bar,log,dog,0,0,0
/^test$/,bar,log,dog,0,0,0
one
FOO,,frog,frog,1,1,1
```

The resulting text file should have the duplicate `foo` removed (order does not matter to me so long as the duplicates are removed, leaving 1 unique)

```
test,bar,log,dog,0,0,0
one
/^test$/,bar,log,dog,0,0,0
one
FOO,,frog,frog,1,1,1
```

What's the simplest bash command I could do to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk -F, '!seen[tolower($1)]++' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `awk` like this (since you don't care which of the duplicates gets kept):

```
awk -F, '{lines[tolower($1)]=$0}END{for (l in lines) print lines[l]}'
```

If you wanted to keep the first instead:

```
awk -F, '{if (lines[tolower($1)]!=1) { print; lines[tolower($1)]=1 } }'
```

Comment: I think you need to fix like so: { print; lines[tolower($1)]=1 }

Comment: @maverick Ooops... missed that one. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Search for

```
(?:(?<=\n)|^)(.*)((?:,(?:d|l|fr)og){2}(?:,[01]){3})(?=\n)([\s\S]*)(?<=\n).*\2(?:\n|$)
```

...and replace with

```
$1$2$3
```

Comment: So what would be the exact command I run from the cli, passing the path of the text file as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for line in $(cat $1)
do
    key=$( echo ${line%%,*} | awk '{print tolower($0)}')

    found=0
    for k in ${keys[@]} ; do [[ "$k" == "$key" ]] && found=1 && break ; done
    (( found )) && continue

    echo $line
    keys=( "${keys[@]}" "$key" )
done
```

Using an array instead of an association (hash), which is less performant. But it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat -n file | 
sort -fk2,2 |
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/^.{7}([^,]*),[^,]*(,(d|l|fr)og){2}(,[01]){3}\n(.{7}\1,[^,]*(,(d|l|fr)og){2}(,[01]){3})$/\5/i;ta;P;D' |
sort -n |
sed -r 's/^.{7}//'
```

1. Number each line.
2. Sort by the first key (ignoring case)
3. Remove duplicates (based on specific criteria)
4. Sort reduced file back into original order
5. Remove line numbers